# Broken Note3 screen with password and debugging mode off need to transfer date any soluations

Tags: usb-debugging, samsung-galaxy-note-3, broken-screen

Broken Note3 screen with password and debugging mode off need to transfer date any solutions,

i need to transfer Avery important date from my mobile, my computer recognize it but no data shown as i use password, i need to open the password to take my date 
i know my password but i cant even type it the screen is dead
pleasssssssse help me
any smart solution?

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! Have you already seen our [broken-screen tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/broken-screen/info)? We've collected some first aid there.

Answer (score 0):

Custom recoveries have ADB on by default, all you need to do is mount the partitions in recovery and pull data.

My bet is to flash a recovery image via Odin (CWM preferable, because it accepts hardware key control), boot to said recovery (only requires hardware key combo), connect to PC and use ADB pull to pull whatever data out of its misery.

Comment: please can you explain more as i do not get you well

Comment: @Amira It's natural that you don't understand me well, because this is going to be a very hard process. Unless you understand ADB usage well and can operate blindly in a custom recovery, I suggest sending the phone to someone else capable instead of risking it yourself.